# Cannot convert value of type 'Any' to specified type in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, nsmutablearray

I have created one array like below

```
var childControllers = NSArray()
childControllers = NSArray(objects: OBDPage1, OBDPage2, OBDPage3, OBDPage4)
self.loadScrollView(page: 0)// calling method
```

now I want to use array object like below

```
func loadScrollView(page: Int){ // method
    if page >= childControllers.count {
        return
    }
    // replace the placeholder if necessary
    let controller: OBDPage1ViewController? = childControllers[page]
}
```

but I am getting below error

> Swift-CarAssist/Swift-CarAssist/OBDCarMonitorDeatilViewController.swift:90:67: Cannot convert value of type 'Any' to specified type 'OBDPage1ViewController?'

can any one tell me where I am going wrong as I am new to swift.

Thanks in advance.
Priyanka

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Working in Swift you should use Swift `Array` rather than `NSArray`

```
var childControllers = [UIViewController]()
childControllers = [OBDPage1,OBDPage2,OBDPage3,OBDPage4]
self.loadScrollView(page: 0)// calling method
```

then

```
func loadScrollView(page: Int){ // method

    if page >= childControllers.count {
        return
    }

    // replace the placeholder if necessary
    let controller = childControllers[page] as? OBDPage1ViewController

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
let controller = childControllers[page] as! OBDPage1ViewController
```

You have to explicitly cast the array value as an `OBDPage1ViewController`, otherwise it is just of type `Any`.

**Edit:**

To be more safe, it is recommended that you perform this using if-let conditional binding.

```
if let controller = childControllers[page] as? OBDPage1ViewController {
    //do something    
}
```

Comment: Please don't recommend using `!` as the first solution, use `as?` which is safer and handle the error.